# PHP order element in an array by their frequency

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$recs = array(1,4,7,1,5,4,1,12,1,4,6,5);
```

I want to get the most frequent item followed by the next most frequent item until I get to the least frequent item and then create another array with this information that looks like this:

```
$frequencies=array("1"=>4,"4"=>3,"5"=>2,"6"=>1,"7"=>1)
```

How can I achieve this, please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to Use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
<?php

$recs = array(1,4,7,1,5,4,1,12,1,4,6,5);

$recs1 = array_count_values($recs);

print_r($recs1);
```

https://eval.in/973006

Or if you want numbers need to be ascending order(which are keys in your final array) then use [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

```
<?php

$recs = array(1,4,7,1,5,4,1,12,1,4,6,5);

$recs1 = array_count_values($recs);
ksort($recs1);
print_r($recs1);
```

https://eval.in/973163

Answer (score 0):

```
$recs = array(1,4,7,5,5,4,5,12,1,4,6,5);
//array_count_values — Counts all the values of an array
$recs1 = array_count_values($recs);
//to get the most frequent item followed by the next most 
//frequent item until I get to the least frequent item 
//use `arsort` — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association
arsort($recs1);
print_r($recs1);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gbtJP)

Comment: worked like charm. thank you